# Rate of convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

What would be the rate of convergence of:

$$\sum^N_n \frac{\mu(n) \log(n)}{n}$$

?

I know that as $N \to \infty$ the series approaches to $-1$, but I am not able to get how fast it does converge using big-O notation. Any help?

*Edit 1:* as noted in the comments, this series equals

$$\lim_{s\to 1^+} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta^2(s)}$$

Thank you.

Comment: but the mobius inversion is only valid for when we are summing through all factors of N right?

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{n^s}=-\frac{d}{ds}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)^2}.$$

Comment: @Jack Thank you, I did not realise that obvious fact... Thanks!

Comment: really? i have to say - to my untrained eye, that was very elegant and powerful. How would we analyse the rate of convergence (in (O) notation) using this?

Comment: Assuming the Riemann hypothesis, the convergence is $O(N^{\varepsilon - \frac{1}{2}})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. But since we haven't proven RH yet, and don't even know any $\alpha < 1$ such that $\zeta$ has no zeros with $\operatorname{Re} s > \alpha$, it could be arbitrarily slow.

Comment: The PNT shows $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log n = -1+\mathcal{O}((\log N)^{-m})$ for every fixed $m$, where $-1 = \lim_{s\to 1^+} \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta^2(s)}$. And the error term is $\mathcal{O}(N^{\sigma-1+\epsilon})$ iff $\zeta$ has no zeros for $\Re(s) > \sigma$ @DanielFischer